# ng-disabled is not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

This might be a silly question. But I just started experimenting with AngularJS. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong in validation. The button is not disabled even when the fields are invalid.

What's the difference between
 `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` and

```
ng-disabled="myForm.cuisine.$invalid || myForm.title.$invalid || myForm.description.$invalid || myForm.cost.$invalid"
```

I think using `myForm.$invalid` is a cleaner way of disabling the button. Any tips?

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select ng-required="true" name="cuisine" ng-model="model.food.cuisine" class="form-control" type="text">
            <option ng-repeat="c in model.cuisines" value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
        </select>
        <p ng-show="myForm.cuisine.$invalid && myForm.cuisine.$touched">
            Please select cuisine type.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input ng-required="true" name="title" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="25" ng-model="model.food.title"
               type="text" class="form-control">
        <p ng-show="myForm.title.$invalid && myForm.title.$touched">Please pick a valid title with atleast 4
            characters.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <textarea ng-required="true" name="description" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="255"
                      ng-model="model.food.description" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <p ng-show="myForm.description.$valid && myForm.description.$touched">Please describe your food with 10 - 255
            characters.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="cost" ng-pattern="/0-9/" ng-required="true" min="1" ng-model="model.food.cost" type="number"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Cost">
        <p ng-show="myForm.cost.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid number</p>
        <p ng-show="myForm.cost.$invalid && myForm.cost.$touched">Please enter cost of food item.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add Food</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is the button inside the form div?

Comment: Yes. For some reason it's not displaying </form>

Comment: Its working http://plnkr.co/edit/wGd5c1NQl4fKnFh6dDLZ

Comment: I don't know why it's not working on local

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, validations don't work if the form element is inside the body of a table.

It works fine if I moved the form tag outside the table.

Thanks everyone.